# Unresolved external symbol errors in Chilkat library dispite including crypt32.dll and ws2_32.dll in Qt 5.15.0 MSVC2015 64x

Tags: c++, qt, include, libraries, chilkat

I try to use Chilkat in Qt for MD5 encryption, but I get lots of unresolved external symbol errors.

my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x64" -lSDL2 \
-ldxguid \
-L"C:\Windows\System32" -lcrypt32 -lws2_32 \
-L"C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2015\libs" -lChilkatRelDll_x64

INCLUDEPATH += C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.4\include \
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2015\include
```

I just put this in the .pro file, am I missing some steps? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the .pro file like this and it works for now.

```
win32:LIBS += -L"C:\Windows\System32" -lcrypt32 \
-lws2_32

LIBS += -L"C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x64" -lSDL2 \
-ldxguid \
-L"C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2015\libs" -lChilkatRelDll_x64 \
-lChilkatDbgDll_x64

INCLUDEPATH += C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.4\include \
C:\chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2015\include
```